# Battery Consumption too high

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, battery

I’ve noticed in the last couple of days that the battery of my iPhone XR is not lasting as long as it used to, its maximum capacity is 90%.

In the last 2 hours I’ve lost 80% of my charge only watching YouTube video using Wi-Fi.

In the battery usage by app section of the battery settings, i see that Photos app used the 33% in the last 24 hours, I’ve checked in the app but I wasn’t uploading/downloading anything from iCloud.

I am running iOS 14.1.

My question is simple, how and why do I have these problems? Could they be caused by a widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is simple, how and why do I have these problems? Could they be caused by a widget?

It can be caused by *anything* including (a) widget(s).

However, in this case, it's an issue with iOS 14.

- [Apple Confirms iOS 14 Battery, Data Problems For iPhone Users](https://www.forbes.com/sites/gordonkelly/2020/10/03/apple-iphone-problem-ios-14-battery-drain-factory-reset/#6e1840d748b8)
- [iOS 14 Battery Life Bad & Draining Fast? Here’s Why & How to Fix It](https://osxdaily.com/2020/09/27/ios-14-battery-life-fix/)

I have personally tested this after experiencing severe battery drain on my iPhone after upgrading to iOS 14.1 by reverting to iOS 13 via a restore from backup.  When I did, the issue went away.

What can you do to fix?  There are some tips like ensuring your apps are updated and closing apps (not suspending them) when not in use.  I personally just keep the phone plugged in all the time and I'm waiting for a new release that hopefully fixes it (actually, I'm waiting for the iPhone 12 mini instead).

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, I’ll wait then